# subprocess.Popen shell=True to shell=False when using ssh command

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have the command:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sshpass -p root ssh root@(IP_ADRESS) 'cd
/home/pi/reed && python reed.py'"],  shell=True,
stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
```

the `shell=True` is dangerous, so I want to avoid it and use `shell=False`.

Any hint?

Comment: How does your code fail when you simply change `shell=True` to `shell=False`? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You should split your command. Like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("sshpass -p root ssh root@(IP_ADRESS) 'cd /home/pi/reed && python reed.py'".split(), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sshpass", "-p", "root", "ssh", "root@(IP_ADRESS)", "cd /home/pi/reed && python reed.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
```

Comment: that executes nicely, but I thought I can avoid the:Accepted password for root from 192.168.178.55 port 33116 ssh2 but that is still in - but that is still there (?)

Comment: What do you mean? Is that some output from your command not being caught by `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`?

Comment: No this is displayed in the logfile of the remote raspberry, which I am calling from the other one - looks like a ssh attack, "someone" trying out ports like crazy (every sec 3 attempts)